# Python shell access to a separate running script

Tags: python, shell, process

I have Python application running on a web server via mod_wsgi and I am able to access python shell through SSH on the server. Part of the application generates a dictionary and a small number of lists in memory over time while the application is running.

Is there a possible way of starting the Python shell on the server and being able to access the dictionary and lists through the shell or is the only option to program the application to pickle or json them and store them in a file periodically or by event trigger?

Even if this is not focused on a web server situation is it possible for a Python shell to access an already running Python application?

Answer (score 1):

You can't generally access one Python interpreter from another.

The most general way to do something like is to put an interpreter-on-a-socket (or -pipe or whatever) into your server program, and just connect your shell up to that interpreter.

Doing this on top of the `code` module isn't hard, but to make it as nice as the normal interactive interpreter shell takes a bit more work. I believe IDLE and IPython both contain lots of useful source code, and possibly even something you can use out of the box, or with minimal changes.

It's also possible to share data directly between two separate programs. For example, use `multiprocessing.Value` on top of `mmap`—or, more simply, just keep the data in a database file instead of in memory. Then your shell can just read the data without interacting directly with the server. However, this means having appropriate locks in place, or trying to write as atomically as possible and accepting that the shell will still occasionally get garbage because of races.

But really, most of the time, if you can afford to dump the data by pickling/JSON/whatever, that's both the easiest and the safest solution.